# use e.rowindex and e.columnindex outside the datagridview events

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, pass-by-reference, eventargs

In a method I want to use

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
```

and

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.ColumnIndex]
```

How can I use  **e.RowIndex** and **e.ColumnIndex** outside the

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

can we **pass DataGridViewCellEventArgs e** ?

or what can be done ?

sample code

```
 var a = datatable1.Rows[e.RowIndex][0].ToString();
 var b = datatable1.Rows[0][e.ColumnIndex].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the currently selected row and column you can use

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
```

and

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
```

Comment: no i was trying to pass e 
but just for now i have used int a=e.rowindex;
and int b=e.columnindex;
and passed them in to method
public void mymethod(int a,int b)